# Laravel PHP Version Error

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am in a trouble with Laravel 5.1 version. I have built it on Ubuntu Platform with PHP 5.5.9. Then I got the following error:

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting ')'
```

And these are the codes which return the error:

```
 <?php
 interface foo {
 }

 class class_with_method_that_declares_anonymous_class
 {
     public function method()
     {
         $o = new class { public function foo() {} };
         $o = new class{public function foo(){}};
         $o = new class extends stdClass {};
         $o = new class extends stdClass {};
         $o = new class implements foo {};
     }
 }
```

Another one:

```
 <?php
 class Test {
     public function methodOne() {
        $foo = new class {
            public function method_in_anonymous_class() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        return $foo->method_in_anonymous_class();
    }

    public function methodTwo() {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

I searched for the solution, then I was informed about the PHP version of Ubuntu. Afterwards, I updated PHP version from 5.5.9 to 5.6.17. But still I am getting the same error. What is wrong in here?

Comment: It could be any number of things, especially since it's so large. Look at the rest of the error (file, line number is usually listed) to see where it's being called at. Or you can try this on the command-line in the main laravel directory: `find . -name \*.php -exec php -l "{}" \; | egrep -v 'No syntax'`

Comment: Provide the piece of code that the error specifies to be able to help you, the error is vague.

Comment: ok I added the code above.

Comment: @OnurGöker Are you using anonymous classes ? If yes, then you need to upgrade your PHP verion to PHP 7 . After that you can use the above code..

Answer (score -1):

You cannot declare classes inside class-methods in PHP.

Comment: anonymous classes were added in PHP 7

Comment: The usage in this code is avaliable since PHP 5.5.X See: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php

Comment: I should have ended my sentence with _having that version of PHP installed_. My fault, I guess it would have been a better answer from my part.